# SetTimeout Firing Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

This is the React code that I have for a page:

```js
function ExportViewerPage(): JSX.Element {
  const [hasPrinted, setHasPrinted] = useState(false);

  if (!hasPrinted) {
    setHasPrinted(true);
    console.log("Inside if loop, hasPrinted: ", hasPrinted)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Executing setTimeout: ", hasPrinted)
    });
  }

  return (<div>Page</div>)
}

export default ExportViewerPage;
```

Ultimately, the code should execute the code in the `setTimeout` function once. However, it actually executes twice as seen in the console here:

```
Inside if loop, hasPrinted:  false
Executing setTimeout:  false
Executing setTimeout:  false
```

The weird thing is that the console log immediately before the `setTimeout` function only executes once, so the `setTimeout` is not being called twice and `hasPrinted` is getting set correctly. This is happening on both Chrome and Firefox.

I did notice that if I turn `reactStrictMode` off in the `next.config.js` file, the `setTimeout` will only fire once. But I am still confused as to why the `setTimeout` is firing twice with `reactStrictMode` on but the console log immediately above it is only logging once.

Comment: i think this is a Dev thing. it will disappear once u deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to strict mode. Per the [docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), strict mode invokes certain functions twice in development to help identify side-effects.

The peculiar part was that the console log above the `setTimeout` wasn't firing twice as well. This can be explained by this snippet from the docs:

> Note:
> In React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in certain cases where a workaround can be used.

Since I am using React 17, the second invocation of the console log was silenced by react, so that's why I was confused.

Note that this is no longer the case in React 18:

> Starting from React 18, React does not suppress any logs. However, if you have React DevTools installed, the logs from the second call will appear slightly dimmed. React DevTools also offers a setting (off by default) to suppress them completely.